# deb error installing the kernel image

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualbox, deb

I just compile the way debian 4.6 kernel and generates deb me with the image and headers package, installing the image I get the following error

```
    Preparing to unpack linux-image-4.6.0linux-4.6_1.0.NAS_amd64.deb ...
    Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.6.0linux-4.6 /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0linux-4.6
    Done.
    Unpacking linux-image-4.6.0linux-4.6 (1.0.NAS) over (1.0.NAS) ...
    Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.6.0linux-4.6 /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0linux-4.6
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.6.0linux-4.6 /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0linux-4.6
    Setting up linux-image-4.6.0linux-4.6 (1.0.NAS) ...
    Running depmod.
    Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.6.0linux-4.6 /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0linux-4.6
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.6.0linux-4.6 /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0linux-4.6
    Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.6.0linux-4.6 (x86_64)
    Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build/make.log for more information.
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.6.0linux-4.6 /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0linux-4.6
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.6.0linux-4.6
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.6.0linux-4.6 /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0linux-4.6
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.6.0linux-4.6 /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0linux-4.6
    Generating grub configuration file ...
    Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0linux-4.6
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.6.0linux-4.6
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.0.0-kali1-amd64
    Found Ubuntu 15.04 (15.04) on /dev/sda1
    Found Fedora release 23 (Twenty Three) on /dev/mapper/fedora-root
    done
```

/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build/make.log

```
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-4.3.28 for kernel 4.6.0linux-4.6 (x86_64)
Sun May 29 18:56:48 PET 2016
make: Entering directory '/home/kevin/Documents/aca/linux-4.6'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build/built-in.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build/vboxdrv/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c: In function ‘VBoxDrvLinuxUnload’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:455:8: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     rc = misc_deregister(&gMiscDeviceUsr);
        ^
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:460:8: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     rc = misc_deregister(&gMiscDeviceSys);
        ^
scripts/Makefile.build:291: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:440: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build/vboxdrv' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build/vboxdrv] Error 2
Makefile:1428: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build' failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.28/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/kevin/Documents/aca/linux-4.6
```

besides the kernel version it did not appear to be selected at boot grub, and update it

Answer (score 1):

The errors are noted in your log:

> error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
>
> ```
> rc = misc_deregister(&gMiscDeviceUsr);
>    ^
> ```
>
> error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
>
> ```
> rc = misc_deregister(&gMiscDeviceSys);
>    ^
> ```

`misc_deregister()` was made a `void` function in kernel by [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f368ed6088ae9c1fbe1c897bb5f215ce5e63fa1e) commit (around k4.3). Now it doesn't return any value, but old VirtualBox kernel module is trying to use it as if it returns something (that was a case before mentioned commit).

You need to use newer VirtualBox (where this is already patched) or patch your VirtualBox manually. See corresponding VirtualBox [commit](https://www.virtualbox.org/changeset/57839/vbox) that fixes it.